# Send ctrl-c to channel in ruby's Net::SSH gem

Tags: ruby, ssh

An [older version](https://net-ssh.github.io/ssh/v1/chapter-3.html) of Net::SSH had #send_signal. Since that method no longer seems to be available, have tried sending "\cC" via #send_data, and also tried closing the channel, but the remote command continues running.

What's the right way to send signals to a Net::SSH::Channel now?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code that you're using to launch this remote process which you're trying to signal.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `request_pty` to create a pseudo-terminal. You can use that terminal to send an interrupt command.

Comment: Had tried to go down that route, but request_pty fails (success==false), and not sure how to get past the failure.

Comment: Also not certain what to do w/ the channel provided in the request_pty block as it doesn't have a #send_signal method either.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a PTY, you can't send control characters. This can be as easy as calling `request_pty`.

It took me a while to figure out, mostly as my system is a bit more complicated - I have multiple SSH sessions running and another thread needs to cause all channels to terminate, so my code looks something like this:

```
def do_funny_things_to_server host,user
    Net::SSH.start(host, user) do |ssh|
        @connections << ssh
        ssh.open_channel do |chan|
            chan.on_data do |ch, data|
                puts data
            end
            # get a PTY with no echo back, this is mostly to hide the "^C" that
            # is otherwise output when I interrupt the channel
            chan.request_pty(modes: [ [ Net::SSH::Connection::Term::ECHO, 0] ])
            chan.exec "tail -f /some/log/file"
        end
        ssh.loop(0.1)
        @connections.delete ssh
    end
end

def cancel_all
    @connections.each do |ssh|
        ssh.channels.each do |id,chan|
            chan.send_data "\x03"
        end
    end
end
```

###Rant:

There's so little documentation about how to use `request_pty` parameters that it can be said to not exist. I had to figure out `modes:` by reading both the source of `net-ssh` and the [SSH RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254) and sprinkling some educated guesses about the meaning of the word "flags" in [section 8 of the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#section-8).

Someone pointed in [another relevant (though not Ruby specific) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44354466/53538) that there's a `"signal"` message that can be used to send signals over the SSH connection, but also that OpenSSH (the implementation I use for the server) does not support it. If your server supports it, you might want to try to use it like this:

```
channel.send_channel_request 'signal', :string, 'INT'
```

See [`"signal"` channel message in the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#section-6.9) and the [`buffer.rb` source file](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/blob/master/lib/net/ssh/buffer.rb) to understand the parameters. Insert here the expected rant about complete lack of documentation of how to use `send_channel_request`. The above suggestion is mostly to document for myself how to use this method.

The answer linked above also mentions an SSH extension called `"break"` which is supposedly supported by OpenSSH, but I couldn't get it to work to interrupt a session.