# How to avoid interrupting SSH command with SIGINT when running in background

Tags: linux, ssh, tcp, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a shell script that launches a few commands on a remote machine.

```sh
ssh -n -S $socket -L port:localhost:port host -tt "remote_command" &
# ....
local_command
```

Where `local_command` is an interactive program (e.g., GDB) running on my local machine and communicating with the `remote_command`. The latter is listening on a TCP port.

While interacting with `local_command`, the remote program closes immediately after a Ctrl+C.

My intuition is that the SSH process receives a termination signal (may be SIGINT?) and closes, and since it is launched within a terminal, the `remote_command` also terminates.

Running ssh with `-v` gives the following message

```
Shared connection to <host> closed.
debug1: channel 1: free: mux-control, nchannels 10
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

So my question is:

- How can I run SSH in a completely detached manner to avoid intercepting the signals on the local host?
- Or, how can I keep the SSH session from intercepting signals?

Things I tried:

- Running the SSH command without `-tt` doesn't forward SIGnals. The caveat is that it leads to SSH process termination but the program `remote_command` keeps running on the remote, and I want to be sure that the program `remote_command` stops when I issue a

```sh
ssh -O exit -S $socket host
```

- Using `-nf` options didn't help either.
- Running the SSH process using `nohup` didn't help either.
- A couple of other posts advised using `-o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o ServerAliveCountMax=20 -o ServerAliveInterval=120`, but it didn't change anything.

Another constraint is that any other solution should be shell POSIX-compliant.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348083/how-to-send-sigint-ctrl-c-to-current-remote-process-over-ssh-without-t-optio) help?

Comment: I just ended up trapping over SIGINT signals just after launching the SSH command
```trap 'my_func "${PARAM1}"' INT
```